# Does document "depth" affect CouchDB performance?

Tags: performance, database-design, couchdb

I have a project where it is very tempting to use a deeply nested collection of data. But how does that affect performance? Are there any reasons why I should avoid doing this? I'm talking about lists in lists in lists, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3636594/425809) StackOverflow thread, it sounds like lists are created by serializing and then deserializing the data.

If you were deeply nesting your documents with list inside of list, that would be a serious performance hit purely from the serialization and deserialization.

If you have a hierarchy like this, I would consider using MySQL, since it's designed for relational data.  It would be simple to implement a hierarchy using a relational DBMS compared to CouchDB.